# C# Remove duplicated objects from list and increase first

Tags: c#, linq

I have an list of objects => `class Example { int quantity; string name; string comment; }` and I want to remove all duplicates and increase the `quantity` by the number of duplicates that have the same `name` and `comment`.

Example:

```
[
    {quantity: 1, name: "Hello", comment: "Hello there"},
    {quantity: 2, name: "Bye", comment: "Good bye"},
    {quantity: 1, name: "Hi", comment: "Hi there"},
    {quantity: 1, name: "Hello", comment: "Hello there"},
    {quantity: 1, name: "Bye", comment: "Good bye"},
]
```

and the result it should be:

```
[
    {quantity: 2, name: "Hello", comment: "Hello there"},
    {quantity: 3, name: "Bye", comment: "Good bye"},
    {quantity: 1, name: "Hi", comment: "Hi there"}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: GroupBy the name/comment combo, then select the group key properties and the Sum() of the Quantities.

Comment: Note that your example isnt C#. Is this a json question, or was that just an example?

Comment: Yes, just an example.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

```
Example[] before = new Example[]
{
    new Example { Quantity = 1, Name = "Hello", Comment = "Hello there" },
    new Example { Quantity = 2, Name = "Bye", Comment = "Good bye" },
    new Example { Quantity = 1, Name = "Hi", Comment = "Hi there" },
    new Example { Quantity = 1, Name = "Hello", Comment = "Hello there" },
    new Example { Quantity = 1, Name = "Bye", Comment = "Good bye" },
};

Example[] after =
    before
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Comment }, x => x.Quantity)
        .Select(x => new Example { Quantity = x.Sum(), Name = x.Key.Name, Comment = x.Key.Comment })
        .ToArray();
```

That gives:

[image: after]

---

Perhaps this version is a little clearer:

```
Example[] after =
    before
        .GroupBy(
            x => new { x.Name, x.Comment },
            (k, xs) => new Example
            {
                Quantity = xs.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                Name = k.Name,
                Comment = k.Comment
            })
        .ToArray();
```

Or perhaps this:

```
Example[] after =
(
    from x in before
    group x.Quantity by new { x.Name, x.Comment } into xs
    select new Example
    {
        Quantity = xs.Sum(x => x),
        Name = xs.Key.Name,
        Comment = xs.Key.Comment
    }
).ToArray();
```

Comment: wonderful, can you please explain a little in group section `, f => f.Quantity ` is not part of keys at this level where it goes in the list/array, in select section `Quantity = x.Sum()` how does it know that sum for Quantity

Comment: `.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Comment }, x => x.Quantity)` is the same as `group x.Quantity by new { x.Name, x.Comment }`. So each group is just an enumerable of `Quantity`, hence `x.Sum()` works.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to remove all duplicates

You haven't defined when two example objects are "duplicates". I guess, that you mean to say, that if two Examples objects have the same values for properties `Name` and `Comment`, then they are duplicates.

Normally you can use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) to find Duplicates. Use the overload with a parameter `resultSelector` to define exactly what you want as result.

```
IEnumerable<Example> examples = ...
var result = examples.GroupBy(

    // key: Name-Comment
    example => new
    {
        Name = example.Name,
        Comment = example.Comment,
    }

    // parameter resultSelector: for every Name/Comment combination and all
    // Examples with this Name/Comment combination make one new example:
    (nameCommentCombination, examplesWithThisNameCommentCombination) => new Example
    {
         Name = nameCommentCombination.Name,
         Comment = nameCommentCombination.Comment,

         // Quantity is the sum of all Quantities of all Examples with this
         // Name/Comment combination
         Quantity = examplesWithThisNameCommentCombination
                    .Select(example => example.Quantity)
                    .Sum(),
    });
```

This will only  work if you want exact string equality. Are "Hello" and "HELLO" equal? And how about "Déjà vu" and "Deja vu"? Do you want case insensitivity for Name and Comment? And how about diacritical characters?

If you want more than just plain string equality, consider to create an ExampleComparer class.

```
class ExampleComparer : EqualityComparer<Example>
{
    ... // TODO: implement
}
```

Usage would be:

```
IEnumerable<Example> examples = ...
IEqualityComparer<Example> comparer = ...

var result = examples.GroupBy(example => example,  // key

    // resultSelector:
    (key, examplesWithThisKey) => new Example
    {
         Name = key.Name,
         Comment = key.Comment,
         Quantity = examplesWithThiskey.Sum(example => example.Quantity),
    },

    comparer);
```

### Implement the ExampleComparer

```
class ExampleComparer : EqualityComparer<Example>
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<Example> ByNameComment {get;} = new ExampleComparer;

    private static IEqualityComparer<string> NameComparer => StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
    private static IEqualityComparer<string> CommentComparer => StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
```

I chose for two separate string comparers, so if later you decide different comparison, for instance Name has to match exactly, then you only have to change it here.

```
public override bool Equals (Example x, Example y)
{
    // almost every Equals method starts with the following three lines
    if (x == null) return y == null;                // true if both null
    if (y == null) return false;                    // false, because x not null
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;  // same object

    // return true if both examples are considered equal:
    return NameComparer.Equals(x.Name, y.Name)
        && CommentComparer.Equals(x.Comment, y.Comment);
}

public override int GetHashCode(Example x)
{
     if (x == null) return 5447125;       // just a number

     return NameComparer.GetHashCode(x.Name)
          ^ CommentComparer.GetHashCode(x.Comment);
}
```

Note: this will also work if Name or Comment are null or empty!

I used `operator ^ (XOR)`, because that gives a fairly good hash if there are only two fields to consider. If you think that the vast majority of Examples have unique names, consider to check only property Name:

```
return NameComparer.GetHashCode(x.Name);
```

Because method `Equals` uses the NameComparer and CommentComparer to check for equality, make sure you use the same Comparers to calculate the HashCode.

Comment: Useful tool: [HashCode.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.combine?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution, which gives you the answer in the List tata but you can do .ToArray() if you wish.

```
    public class Example 
    { 
        public int quantity; 
        public string name; 
        public string comment; 
    }

    Example[] toto = new Example[]
    {
        new Example
        {
            quantity = 1,
            name = "Hello",
            comment = "Hello there"
        },
        new Example
        {
            quantity = 2,
            name = "Bye",
            comment = "Good bye"
        },
        new Example
        {
            quantity = 1,
            name = "Hi",
            comment = "Hi there"
        },
        new Example
        {
            quantity = 1,
            name = "Hello",
            comment = "Hello there"
        },
         new Example
        {
            quantity = 1,
            name = "Bye",
            comment = "Good bye"
        }
    };

    List<Example> tata = new List<Example>();
    foreach (Example exa in toto)
    {
        bool found = false;
        foreach (Example exb in tata)
        {
            if (exb.name == exa.name && exb.comment == exa.comment)
            {
                exb.quantity += exa.quantity;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            tata.Add(exa);
        }
    }
```

A good exercise would be to LINQ that!

Comment: Euww, nested loops.. Dictionary please

Comment: @CaiusJard What's the problem with nested loops? Can you elaborate, please? How would you do with a dictionary? We have three entries here, not two.

Comment: *What's the problem with nested loops* - approaching O(n²).. *How would you do with a dictionary?* - make the key a `new { name, comment}` or `(name, comment)` or record; AT, ValueTuples and records have built in equality/hashing of all their constituent props

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks! And internally, are not all the solutions equivalent to the 2 nested loops? I mean, doing LINQ or the DICT thing would take time, no?

Comment: It might depend, but generally the answer is "no". When a list is finding something, it starts at the beginning and checks every item. When a dictionary is finding something it calculates where it expects the item will be and goes there and looks at the item; if it's not the right one there is a pointer to another item (your princess is in another castle) which might be the right one. If they were recipe books, a list is like "turn every page one by one looking for the double mega chocolate cake, find it on page 97 after 96 failed attempts" whereas a dictionary is like..

Comment: ..turn to the index and locate "chocolate cake: first recipe on page 46", go to p46 and see it's a chocolate cheesecake, not the double mega, but then you see "there is another chocolate cake recipe on p97", turn to 97 and you got your item. If there is only one chocolate cake recipe in the book you go straight there. If there are multiple, it can take some time. If the whole book is nothing but chocolate cake variations (highly unlikely, but conceptually possible) then yes, you have to check the whole book in which case it performs as badly as a list

Comment: Enimgativity's LINQ isn't quite as efficient as building a dict directly but it's a little easier to code. LINQ generally uses a mix of loops and sets to give its answers. GroupBy uses some kind of internal dictionary to collect items under a common key and is then easy to convert to a dictionary. GroupBy could, but wouldn't, internally use nested loops and lists to aggregate items - you can see the source code at https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs if you're ever having trouble sleeping; the interesting stuff goes on circa line 2200